# Can the commercial night cross country be done under IFR?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

The below doesn't mention anything about needing to be night IFR, so if you were to shoot an approach on this flight, would it be legal?  Also, if the instructor isn't a CFII, but PIC does have an instrument rating?

https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.129

> (iv) One 2-hour cross country flight in a single engine airplane in
>   nighttime conditions that consists of a total straight-line distance
>   of more than 100 nautical miles from the original point of departure;
>   and

Comment: You're in FAA-land I take it from the FAR reference? Also, I take it both pilots are IFR rated/current, just there's no CFII in the cockpit?

Comment: If the instructor is not a CFII then if the flight is in IMC the person is just going for the ride and not instructing. I don't know the answer to this question, but my initial reaction is to wonder why you would want to do your flight in night IMC?

Comment: I didn't, but where I fly marine layers some times come in even if not forecasted, so if the flight was vfr, then on the return the cloud deck came in, I'd rather shoot an approach through it than try to go under and scud run.  As it turned out no marine layer and no IMC required.

Comment: Think off the spirit of the rule, not so much the letter of the law.

Comment: In actual or simulated IMC you have removed the NIGHT part of the cross country to just  takeoff and landing. What about all those other nautical miles?

Comment: I don't follow how IMC removes the NIGHT part--It's still dark out.  And en route cruise seems like it'd be the same either way.  In my earlier example you fly to your destination and return.  You get the ATIS and it's fine and clear conditions, then as you approach the VMC turns to a 900 ft ceiling IMC situation, so you need to get a pop up clearance to shoot an approach.  

Some times marine layers come in at 8pm, other times 2am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regulation doesn't specify VFR or IFR, so you may complete that requirement in either.

Comment: Just to corroborate this, I checked my logbook and I did my commercial night cross country under IFR. In my case, I wanted to stay instrument current and it was a good opportunity. It was VMC, but being under the hood at night is much closer to IMC than during the day.